# Displaying % in a label

Tags: java, swing, loading, jlabel

So on my project I have an timer with an label which makes it look like it is Loading so i was wondering how would i make it so there is an % in the middle which after 10 seconds goes to 100% so like 1 second is 10% 1.5seconds is 15%

My Timer

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        m.setVisible(true);

        Close();
        timer.stop();

    }
}
```

And the Label Code

```
Loading = new javax.swing.JLabel();

Loading.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/pkgnew/launcher/Images/Loading Program/Loading.gif"))); // NOI18N

getContentPane().add(Loading);
Loading.setBounds(210, 210, 60, 60);
```

Comment: In the code where you update the UI with the number, add `+ "%"` to it. If you want specifics, you'll have to show code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making progress bars based of a set time is dangerous as a program which runs in 10 seconds on your PC may take 20 on another due to differing hardware, memory e.t.c.  What you may want to look into is a JProgressBar to try and track the progress of whatever you are timing.

Try checking out [java2s](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/0560__JProgressBar.htm) and [Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JProgressBar.html) for a bit more info.

Comment: Could you link me to a tutorial on this ?

Comment: Is the bar Customisable tho

Comment: Did you take the time to read the JProgressBar API? The API has a link to the Swing tutorial. Or did you take the time to search the forum/web using `JProgressBar` as a keyword. Be proactive.